# Append Value of Data-Attribute to Element

Tags: jquery

So I have some jQuery data-attributes that I can access but I need to append the values to an HTML element, but not too sure how to do it.

I'm using a Shopify app called Judge.Me for product reviews, using JS it puts in reviews for each product. There's no HTML markup that I enter in, just a script call.

In the email from support regarding the various elements, they said:

> "We don't have Liquid variables for those data. However, they are available in our review widget's HTML, so you can extract them via JavaScript, jQuery."

The attribute I have is: `$('.jdgm-rev-widg').data('average-rating')` and I'd like to append the `average-rating` to a `<h1></h1>` element.

The code I have so far, albeit rather basic is:

```
<div class="score-board">
    <h1></h1>
</div>


jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var $averageRating = $('.jdgm-rev-widg').data('average-rating')
  $('.score-board h1').append($averageRating);
 })
```

Comment: If you inspect the HTML what does it look like? Where does the `data-average-rating` element exist?

Answer (score 1):

You're targeting your h1 incorrectly. Here's an example of how to target your h1 below. You can either use

```
  $('.score-board > h1').append($averageRating);
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var $averageRating = $('.average-rating').data('average-rating');
  $('.score-board > h1').append($averageRating);
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="average-rating" data-average-rating="5"></div>
<div class="score-board">
  <h1></h1>
<div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, sorry, my H1 is classless within `<div class="score-board"></div>`. 

Does the above code still apply?

Comment: See the new fix :) IT should be working without any problems :D

Comment: Hmmm so I posted the new script code you provided but it doesn't seem to make any change.

Comment: Please provide more context. Where is this element `$('.average-rating').data('average-rating');` coming from

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my question. The element doesn't actually exist, the app I've now mentioned inserts it into the page via JS.

Comment: How is it inserted? Because the script will load as soon as the page is finished loading, so if you're using Ajax the element might not exist which is why you're running into this problem. Do you have a link to the page? @ConduciveMammal

Comment: Via the app's JS.

The only thing I put in my product template is the initial call script tag

`<div id='judgeme_product_reviews' class='jdgm-widget jdgm-review-widget' data-product-title='{{ product.title }}' data-id='{{ product.id }}'>{{ product.metafields.judgeme.widget }}</div>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149296/discussion-between-win-and-conducivemammal).